# x86 Assembly Keyboard Input Without INT

Tags: assembly, input, keyboard

I need to make an animation which will accelerate when the user keeps a key pressed, and return to normal speed when the key is released. I can't "wait" for the user to enter a key like most DOS and BIOS interrupts do, since it'll stop the animation.

I tried to use option 01H INT 16H, which works without pausing the program, but it doesn't clear the keyboard buffer either; thus the animation will stay accelerated even if the key is released, since the key stays in the buffer.

I'm thinking that if I can access the keyboard buffer's memory location manually I can retrieve and erase it myself. But sadly I don't know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use port 060h, get the key press & release status there

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple problems with this. You just can't scan port 0x60 mainly because the same port is SHARED with the mouse. First, you need to scan port 0x64, determine if it's a keyboard or a mouse. And that isn't even set up the PS/2 interface and initializing each different keyboard`s driver (may not be required but it makes the process smoother)

Just go with bios, if you don't look at [OSDev's Instructions](http://wiki.osdev.org/PS2_Keyboard)